# ThymeLeaf gives Internel Server Error. How to fix?

Tags: html, mysql, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

My SpringBoot project gives Internal Server Error, status=500 after implementing below in index.html
it's working with out below part in index.html
But I have no idea what's the issue on below.

```
> <tbody>
>         <tr th:each="product : ${listProducts}">
>             <td th: text="${product.id}">Product ID</td>
>             <td th: text="${product.name}">Name</td>
>             <td th: text="${product.brand}">Brand</td>
>             <td th: text="${product.madein}">Made In</td>
>             <td th: text="${product.price}">Price</td>
>             <td></td>
>         </tr> </tbody>
```

**AppController.java**

```
package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class AppController {



    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<Product> listProducts = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listProducts",listProducts);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**Product.java**

```
package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;



import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Product {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private String madein;
    private float price;

    public Product() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy  = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getMadein() {
        return madein;
    }

    public void setMadein(String madein) {
        this.madein = madein;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

**ProductRepository.java** (interface)

```
package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {


}
```

**ProductService.java**

```
package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository repo;


    public List<Product> listAll(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    public void save(Product product)
    {
        repo.save(product);
    }

    public Product get(Long id){
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void delete(Long id){
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**ProductManagerApplication.java**

```
package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/salesdb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeLeaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Product Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Product Manager</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Made In</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="product : ${listProducts}">
            <td th: text="${product.id}">Product ID</td>
            <td th: text="${product.name}">Name</td>
            <td th: text="${product.brand}">Brand</td>
            <td th: text="${product.madein}">Made In</td>
            <td th: text="${product.price}">Price</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the spaces between `th:` and `text`. It should be `th:text`, not `th: text`.

Comment: Also, there should be a specific error message in the server logs, whenever you get a "Status 500" message. It's always helpful to include that error message in your question.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much